# Music+Video hub opening panorama transition

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, transition

In WP7.1, when one opens a Music+Video hub, a stylish from-around-the-corner-slide-in page transition animation takes place.

It seems like not an entire page is sliding in, but a Panorama control in it.

How can one achieve exactly the same transition animation in application? 
Can it be done with Silverlight for WP7 Toolkit?

Comment: Have you actually tried the Silverlight Toolkit transitions before asking?-)

Comment: Yes I have. And have not been able to achive the exact same transition.

Comment: I think Telerik has some support for things like this in their Windows Phone offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the similar (if not the same) effect one needs to set the turnstile transition animation on PhoneApplicationPage:

```
<Controls:PhoneApplicationPage>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                    <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
                </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
```

And a slide animation on panorama:

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="panorama">
            <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
                <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                        <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideRightFadeIn"/>
                    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
```

Answer (score -1):

TransitionFrame would be what you need. Googling or Binging for samples should be easy.

Comment: I have been using transitions from Silverlight toolkit. None of them seem to be doing the transition from M+V hub. Try Googleing yourself ;) I assure you finding what I have ased about is not easy.

Comment: The Panorama by default has some animation of its own that it plays when it first loads. The problem is that it is pretty quick and if your layout isn't fairly simple, you are loading something in the background or have other performance issues which are hard to avoid on a small device - you might never see it. I have a simple sample application that uses the TransitionFrame with turnstile animations for all pages and when I go back and forth between two panorama pages - I can see a combined animation from the panorama and transition frame that is very similar to the one in the M+V hub.